# Zbar Installation

Tags: python

I'm attempting to install zbar on my raspberry pi. I built the source by entering:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I don't get any errors or warnings from any of the above commands.
After the install finishes, I enter python and attempt to import zbar. Doing this results in a segmentation fault.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: Installing the python-zbar module with apt-get (Raspbian-2013-02-09) generate a segmentation fault on import in python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug into the arm branch of Debian. As today the Raspbian pakager has fixed the bug and released the affected packages.

You can read other details on the [dedicated page Debian bug base](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=702499)